# Put arraylist in hashmap with key as one of the columns

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

I have a resultSet which is having multiple rows. I want to make a hashmap. But while storing the arrayList and making key as one of the columns, for each key all the rows are stored in arrayList.
That means for each key all the rows are stored rather than the exact rows for that key.

- HashMap> map = new HashMap>();
         Pojo pojo = null;
         PreparedStatement ps = null;
         ResultSet rs = null;
         ArrayList list = null;

  ```
     try {
         ps = DatabaseManager.prepareStatement(query);
         ps.setInt(1, number);
         rs = ps.executeQuery();
         while(rs.next()){

           pojo = new Pojo();
           pojo.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
           pojo.setDate(rs.getDate("DATE"));
           pojo.setTotal(rs.getDouble("TOTAL"));

           list.add(pojo); map.put(rs.getInt("ID"), list);
         }
         rs.close();
  ```

> **So for all the keys the size of list is 15. While it should be like 
>   ID      Rows
>   1A        3
>   2A        4
>   3C        2
>   4W        6**

So how the code should be to get the desired result?

Comment: why you want to store key and list in hashmap? Instead you can store key and pojo itself.

Comment: I have multiple rows for a key. So if I store pojo then only one value will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
while(rs.next()){
    // Check if map contains list
    if (map.contains(rs.getInt("ID"))
        list = map.get(rs.getInt("ID"));
    else
        list = new ArrayList<Pojo>();

    pojo = new Pojo();
    pojo.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
    pojo.setDate(rs.getDate("DATE"));
    pojo.setTotal(rs.getDouble("TOTAL"));

    list.add(pojo); 
    map.put(rs.getInt("ID"), list);
}
```

Hope it works.